Is it better or even possible to use one syllable for vocal improv (scatting) or is there a benefit to using multiple syllables?
I really want to be able to focus on just the pitch instead of lyrics of changing syllables when I do vocal improv. I’ve noticed that certain rhythms do not seem to flow as smoothly with one syllable as they do with multiple syllables (“a full word”). Is this because a lack of skill or because certain syllables or combinations of syllables are smoother? I wish I could make it work with just one syllable because again, I would like to focus on the pitches and the overall composition not the lyrical content.
When I do quicker styles of vocals, say rap for example, is it really better to use multiple syllables or phonetics that are quicker like t’s b’s d’s p’s or is that unnecessary and even just using a vowel could work?

Well sure; some things are phonetically hard to do, especially fast. Any wine player can tell you that fast tonguing is hard, and “double tonguing”—alternating physical motions that equate to different phonemes—is easier. The other part of this conversation is about “gesture,“ what a pattern of emphasis does to the shape of the phrase.

For a relevant example, anyone who went to the cinema in the '70s or '80s will know at least one piece sung to a single, repeated syllable: Asteroid, the Pearl & Dean theme!

@AndyBonner +1 for wine player, what we all strive to be!  But yes, double tonguing is a good explanation for why doo bee doo is ubiquitous in scat.

@nuggethead oh and also, do they use vowel before syllable in scat, E.g, oo-doo?

@Lecifer Well, DO they?  You seem to be asking your questions without having actually listened to any scat singing!

Listen to some scat singing.  Do you hear 'Doo doo doo doo dooo...'  or 'Doo-bie doobie doo...' or something else?   Start off by imitation, then see where YOUR musical ideas take YOU.
In rap, you have to do whatever the words ARE of course.  They're chosen for meaning, not just for sound.
Would you agree that it's easier to sing 'squiddly-doo-bee-doo-bee-doo-wah'   than 'doo-doo-doo-doo-doo-doo-doo-doo-doo' on this example?


Using just one syllable for scatting can definitely help you focus on the pitch and overall melody without getting distracted by changing syllables. It can be a useful approach, especially if you're looking to train your ear and really get into the melodic aspect of improvisation. However, you might find that certain rhythms don't flow as smoothly with just one syllable, and that's pretty normal.
The thing is, different syllables have different sounds and articulations that can naturally create more rhythmic interest and variety. For example, using a mix of syllables like "ba," "da," "doo," and "scat" can help add a percussive element to your vocals and make your improvisation sound more dynamic. It's not necessarily about a lack of skill—it's more about the nature of how different sounds interact with rhythm.
When it comes to quicker vocal styles, like rap, using multiple syllables or quicker consonants (like "t," "b," "d," "p") can definitely help you keep up with the rhythm and add clarity to the flow. But if you really prefer to focus on vowels for a specific effect or sound, that can work too—it just might require more precision to maintain clarity and rhythm.
So, there's a balance. If you want to stick to one syllable, that's totally fine, but incorporating a variety can give you more tools to play with in terms of rhythm and texture. It’s all about what you want to express and how you feel comfortable doing it!
Hope that helps!

I've seen multiple jazz methods to teach rhythm and phrasing with simple syllables and the syllables are specifically linked to rhythm. While the idea in these lessons was not specifically about scat singing, the result is essential scat.
A typical example will use an easy to sustain syllable, like "doo", for long rhythms values and a short ending syllable, like "dit", for short short values. In any way this reminds me a solfege for association syllables with specific scale degree, but instead it associates syllables types with rhythm durations.
So, I would say there is a benefit for multiple syllables in scat. It can provide syllables that better match rhythms. The general term for this kind of syllable to rhythm matching is scansion. Normally, scansion deals with lyrics of actual words, but the meaning of the words is not the main concern. The main concern in scansion is natural language accent, which in part comes from syllable duration. Anyway, using multiple scat syllables with help rhythm "scan" better with syllables.
